# node-postgres difference between done() and done(client)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Using node postgres what's the difference between done() and done(client).
According to the docs, if you are using a pool, done() just returns the connection to the pool for future reuse, and done(client) removes the connection from the pool.

My question is, on a long running process, do we really need to remove the connection from the pool on error or we can just log the error or something and then return the connection to the pool for future reuse.

Also, what would be a good value for pg.defaults.poolSize?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: pg.defaults.poolSize depends on Hardware Configuration. We made 100 for our production server in AWS for 4CPU/8GB instance. Gnerally we do not need to remove connection from pool - connection add/remove will be expensive operation

Answer (score 0):

In any process, regardless of how long it is, always call `done()` after executing all the queries needed. And if you do that, you won't need to worry about the pool size.